# Use Of .length in Substring (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, indexof, string-length

Can't figure out why this won't work.

I am trying to analyse a string of variable length containing a "." somewhere inside, and then strip off the "." and all characters before it.  This is called via a web service.

When debugging, it works fine until it bails out at the last line, below, with the browser message:
"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
"

Anyone got any idea?

Code1, below, is an input variable passed to the web service from an eform.

```
Dim CharNo As New Integer
CharNo = Code1.IndexOf(".")
MyCodebookValueStrip.o_Code1 = Code1.Substring(CharNo + 1, (Code1.Length - CharNo))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculation of the lenth of the remaining string is incorrect. You have to subtract one more:

```
Code1.Substring(CharNo + 1, Code1.Length - CharNo - 1)
```

You can also just omit the second parameter, and it will get the rest of the string:

```
Code1.Substring(CharNo + 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try an alternative and very simple approach?

```
MyCodebookValueStrip.o_Code1 = Code1.Split(".").Last()
```

if you're absolutely sure the string does contain a period. Otherwise, use:

```
MyCodebookValueStrip.o_Code1 = Code1.Split(".").LastOrDefault()
```

which will return you 'Nothing' if you're string doesn't contain a period.

If your string contains more than one period, you'll get the substring after the last period in the string back. But you do have scope to do otherwise, e.g.:

```
"StringOne.StringTwo.StringThree".Split(".").First()
```

will give you "StringOne".

```
"StringOne.StringTwo.StringThree".Split(".").Last()
```

will give you "StringThree".

```
"StringOne.StringTwo.StringThree".Split(".").Skip(1).Take(1)
```

will give you "StringTwo".

You'll need to reference and import System.Linq to use this stuff, which means you'll need to be using .NET 3.5 or above.

Comment: Also, this will only work properly if the string only contains one period.

Comment: Indeed, but the original question does specify a single '.'. I've edited to cater for other scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Dim output As String
   Dim Code1 As String = "test.txt"
   Dim charNo As Integer = Code1.IndexOf('.')
   If ((charNo <> -1) And (Code1.Length <> charNo + 1)) Then
      output = Code1.Substring(charNo, Code1.Length - charNo)
   Else
      output = ""
   End If
```

The above works for me flawlessly.. could it be that you're getting a -1 position from the IndexOf method?

Comment: The op is using CharNo - 1 as the first parameter, as the period should not be in the result.

Comment: You left out the fact that he was adding a `+ 1` to the `charNo` inside his call to `SubString`.

Comment: Not spot on, as output will be ".txt", not "txt".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding one to the starting index (`CharNo + 1`), but you don't minus one from the length.  To correct it, you should have written:

```
Code1.Substring(CharNo + 1, (Code1.Length - CharNo - 1))
```

However, it's unnecessary because all you really needed to do was:

```
Code1.Substring(CharNo + 1)
```

Also, you should probably be checking if `CharNo + 1` is less than the length, just in case the period was the last character in the text:

```
If CharNo + 1 < Code1.Length Then
    MyCodebookValueStrip.o_Code1 = Code1.Substring(CharNo + 1)
Else
    MyCodebookValueStrip.o_Code1 = ""
End If
```

However, if what you are trying to get is the extension from a file name, you should be using the `Path` class to do it right (and easier):

```
MyCodebookValueStrip.o_Code1 = Path.GetExtension(Code1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't it be:

```
Code1.Substring(CharNo + 1, (Code1.Length - CharNo - 1))
```

Because `Code1.Length - CharNo` gives you an extra character.

Ex:

```
"abc.abcd"
```

You want the last 4 characters, and `length - charNo` will result in 5. Therefore the error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone.  I should have realised that it needed a -1.
So many right answers here, I'm not sure if I can select more than one as the "accepted answer".  I'll give it a try.
Thanks a lot.